# Getting correct Directory of text file

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, assets

I want to get the correct directory of the `.csv` file, but I don't know how to do that.
Code is as follows:

```
final File file = new File('assets/dataFile.txt');

   Stream<List> inputStream = file.openRead();

  inputStream
      .transform(utf8.decoder) // Decode bytes to UTF-8.
      .transform(new LineSplitter()) // Convert stream to individual lines.
      .listen(
    (line) {
      // Process results.

      List row = map.split(','); // split by comma

      noPara = row[0];
      shortDesc = row[2];
      imgURL = row[4];

      //print('$id, $symbol, $open');
    },
    onDone: () {
      print('File is now closed.');
    },
    onError: (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    },
  );
```

If someone can answer for this it would be great!